# Is there a way to navigate to a default screen (Profile) if the path name does not match a route that I define explicitly?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-navigation, deep-linking

I have tried writing the config object for my react native app according to the [react-navigation configuring links docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links).

I defined a series of path --> route mappings including Chat:'feed' and Explore:'news'

My goal is for the app to default to the Profile screen when resolving https://example.com/someusername and pass 'someusername' as the id param. Similar to how https://instagram.com/apple maps directly to the profile screen for @apple's account.

```
const linking = {
  prefixes: ['https://example.com', 'example://'],
  config: {
    Home: {
      path: '',
      screens: {
        Chat: 'feed',
        Explore: 'news',
        Profile: ':id',
      },
    },
  },
}
```

I will not allow users to make accounts @feed, @news, etc. to avoid conflict. I also display "user not found" message if 'someusername' does not exist yet

Is there a correct way to do this config object? Or if I need to write custom getStateFromPath / getPathFromState functions, does anyone have an example?

Answer (score 5):

We don't have a built-in way to do it right now, but you can provide a custom `getStateFromPath` function to return a different state object:

```js
const linking = {
  prefixes: ['https://mychat.com', 'mychat://'],
  config: {
    Chat: 'feed/:sort',
  },
  getStateFromPath(path, config) {
    // You can perform own checks on the path
    if (isValidPath(path)) {
      return {
        routes: [
          {
            name: 'Home',
            state: {
              routes: [{ name: 'Profile' }],
            },
          },
        ],
      };
    }

    return getStateFromPath(path, config);
  },
};
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-linking#getstatefrompath

Regarding user not found message, I'd recommend handling that in the `Profile` screen itself by checking the params and rendering an error message there.

Comment: Hi! Maybe you could check this out @satya164 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74434223/react-navigation-how-to-pass-same-params-from-a-screen-to-initial-route