# React navigation how to pass same params from a screen to initial route

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

So concerning React Navigation docs, they say that it's possible to pass the same params from a screen to an initial route by using a custom implementation of `getStateFromPath()`

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links#rendering-an-initial-route

[image]

Can anybode show me any example of how to implement a custom getStateFromPath to pass the same params from a screen to its initial route from the following example?

Example:

```
const config: {
  initialRouteName?: any;
  screens: PathConfigMap<RootStackParamsList>;
} = {
    initialRouteName: "ScreenA",
    screens: {
        ScreenA: {
            path: "ScreenA",
            parse: {
                param1: Number,
                param2: Number
            }
        },
        screenB: {
            path: "ScreenB/param1/param2",
            parse: {
                param1: Number,
                param2: Number
            }
        }
    }
}

const linkingOptions: LinkingOptions<ReactNavigation.RootParamList> = {
  prefixes: [Linking.makeUrl("/")],
  config: config,
  getStateFromPath(path, config) {
    // Get params from ScreenB and copy them for screenA
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a route state in `getStateFromPath()`.

```
import { getStateFromPath } from "@react-navigation/native";

getStateFromPath(path, options) {
    if (path.includes("ScreenB")) {
      const params = getStateFromPath(path, options)?.routes[0].params;
      return {
        routes: [
          {
            name: "ScreenA",
            params: {
              ...params,
            },
          },
        ],
      };
    }
    return getStateFromPath(path, options);
  }
```